# Inserting terminal session in to a text file

Tags: vim, terminal, latex, ipython

I want to insert my ipython terminal session in to a text file. The usual way of `ipython >> test.txt` does not work and collect too much garbage.

Preferably I am looking for some thing that does not require the use of this `test.txt` or some intermediary file.

I have seen quite a number of Ipython's code snippets. How do they do it? More specifically I am writing some handouts in `latex` using `vim` and would need frequent insertion of of such sessions. Through `vim` I also tried `:r!ipython`, but it does not work and too much garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save specific lines from the current session into a file with `save <filename> <range>`:

- save line 13 into `filename.py`

  ```
  In [26]: save filename 13
  ```
- save lines 1 to 25 into `filename.py`

  ```
  In [26]: save filename 1-25
  ```
- save lines 6 to 10 and 18 to 25 into `filename.py`

  ```
  In [27]: save filename 6-10 18-25
  ```

You can also use `%edit` to open the specified lines in a text editor:

```
In [55]: edit 23-32
```